# Grub don't find windows 7 loader. Can't boot to windows after installing linux Help

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Last week i installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my windows 7 System and now I am trying to boot into windows and i can't do it.

I installed GRUB-2 and i tried to boot to Windows from there but i can't see the windows loader.

So is there a way to add windows boot to Grub so i can do dual boot with windows and Linux?

I checked and the files are all there. I also used the Windows CD to recover my boot image and still nothing happened. Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first **mount** your **windows partition** in Ubuntu.

then run this in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

now **restart**.

Comment: Still nothing. I update Grub but as i can see it can't find the partition where windows are located.. i am using Gparted to see what partition has windows on it and using this guide i am trying to add windows bootloader on grub but nothing happened.. because i got an error on finding the windows partition. –

Comment: Can you open windows partition in Ubuntu?(in nautilus)

Comment: Are you sure it is searching the correct hard drive? You have two disks by the look of it 'sda' and 'sdb'. Windows is on two partitions of sda and the linux boot files are on sdb. Apart from that, I'm afraid you need more expert help than I can offer.

Comment: Look. i just tried somethnig. i removed the HDD where Linux where installed and windows booted up successfully.. so the only problem i how to add windows on GRUB-2 so i can boot without removeing the HDD

Answer (score 1):

See here for the official help on boot repair : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair

Comment: Still nothing. i cant push the repair windows boot files on boot-repair. here is the URL i got.. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6750406/